# What is the purpose of this black felt on end of oven conduit?

Tags: oven, conduit

I bought an oven which I am installing (reference [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/179437/how-to-wire-up-a-240-v-oven) for details) and I'm confused by the black wrap at the end of the conduit shown in the picture below.

Is the wrap there just to prevent chafing during shipment/storage, and is it supposed to be removed?  It's somewhat long and takes up space in the junction box, so I'd prefer to remove it, but not sure if I can do so safely.

Is the conduit clamp supposed to clamp onto the felt or directly onto the conduit itself?

The conduit is flexible, if that matters.

It's a tough felt-like material with a sticky side.  I'm not sure what it's called.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score -1):

That is called *electrical tape*, also called *fleece tape*.

It is used to keep the wires in a neat bundle.

It is not conductive, so you cannot clamp a grounding strap to it.

Remove it so that you can check for the plastic anti-short bushing at the end of the BX cable jacket.

Comment: I didn't recognize it as electrical tape because I'm not used to seeing the heavy duty style tape, but in retrospect, it's obvious that's what it is after you pointed it out.  Nonetheless, my question still remains unanswered.

Comment: That's a flex whip, NOT BX! (which means that there won't be an anti-short bushing there, as it's not needed for FMC) Also, the tape was factory applied I bet, and probably should not be removed unless the oven install instructions call for it...